# Focus on a specific cell in DataGridView after EndEdit a specific column

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want get focus on the last row and 1st cell on `DataGridView` where user EndEdit the column number 4. This is the code:

```
private void dgvStock_CellEndEdit_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 4)
    {
        dgvStock.CurrentCell = dgvStock.Rows[dgvStock.Rows.Count-1].Cells[1];
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From your picture, you need to be testing for a column index of **2** (not 4).
Also you need to set the Current Cell to be Cell **0** of the last row rather than Cell 1.

```
private void dgvStock_CellEndEdit_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 2)
    {
        dgvStock.CurrentCell = dgvStock.Rows[dgvStock.Rows.Count-1].Cells[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: @user2176268 Do you know whether the EndEdit event is getting fired when it is expected to?